# Polarity question

Tags: polarity, negative-voltage

In a -48 volt DC power plant system how do you determine the polarity of 0v?
trying to resolve an issue and not sure how to correctly identify

Comment: *how do you determine the polarity of 0v* 0 V has no polarity, probably you mean "What is the ground reference?"  "Ground" or "chassis" is the term EEs use to refer to the point that we **define as being 0 Volt**. Very often the (metal) case of a device is connected to ground, test this using a multimeter, connect - to the case and measure the voltage at the battery connections. In a -48 DC system the - contact of the battery will be -48 V, the + will be 0 V.

Comment: Jose - You said that you are "*trying to resolve an issue*". Please explain the issue you are trying to resolve; in other words, please give us more *context* to your question. That will help readers to better understand your question (or to ask better clarification questions to you) since, as *Bimpelrekkie* explained, your question doesn't make much sense as it is currently written *without any context* to help explain it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fagr9I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Negative ground. (b) Positive ground.*

- If the power-supply negative is connected to earth / ground (Fig. 1a) then it will be the zero-volt reference and the other terminal will be +48 V with respect to your ground.
- If the power-supply positive is connected to earth / ground (Fig. 1b) then it will be the zero-volt reference and the other terminal will be -48 V with respect to your ground.
- If the power-supply is not connected to earth / ground (Fig. 1a) then it will be floating with respect to your ground. There will still be 48 V between its terminals but no defined voltage between either terminal and ground.

It seems that you have a system as shown in Figure 1b.

> In a -48 volt DC power plant system how do you determine the polarity of 0v?

- It has no polarity relative to ground.
- It is +48 V relative to the power-supply negative.

Answer (score 0):

That's a question of point of view:

- the voltage is 48 volts more negative than the ground, so it's -48 V relative to ground ;
- but, the ground is 48 volts more positive than your voltage, so it's +48 V relative to your supply voltage.
- you could as well take any other reference if you want.

Comment: -1 Your answer doesn't say anything about the "polarity of 0V", which is the question.